# wxRuby Error : undefined method `register_hot_key'

Tags: wxwidgets, wxruby

I am trying to register a global hotkey using wxruby on Windows 7.

```
require 'wx'
frame = Wx::Frame.new
frame.register_hot_key(100, Wx::MOD_ALT, Wx::K_F1)
```

But I obtain this error message:

`NoMethodError: undefined method register_hot_key for #<Wx::Frame:0x38bfd70>`

`Wx::Frame` inherits from `Wx::Window`, so I would expect that method to be
there. Any ideas on why this doesn not work? Am I doing something wrong?

*(I am using wxruby (2.0.1 x86-mingw32).)*

Answer (score 0):

Change your call to `frame.RegisterHotKey` and it might find it!

Comment: Steve, unfortunately the error persists. Please tell me what can be done? 'wxruby-ruby19-2.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/wx/accessors.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined method "RegisterHotKey" for #<Wx::Frame:0x2b15d70> (NoMethodError)